# Is there a way to script for "refreshing" a given tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So essentially, I create a copy of a spreadsheet for each new client, and I have a workout program template tab ("Week Template") that I duplicate and re-name based upon the week (Week 1, Week 2, Week 3, etc.). I have another tab called "Data" which pulls data from the week tabs, and sorts it according to the tab/sheet name.

I'm using this function for tracking data:
*=if('Week 1'!$A4="SQ",PRODUCT('Week 1'!$E4,'Week 1'!$K4,'Week 1'!$L4),"")*
In this instance, I'm tracking data when the SQ identifier is present.

My issue is that whenever I re-create, say "Week 1", the data won't auto-populate over on "Data" and shows #REF!. However, whenever I double click on the desired cell, it's almost as if the cell refreshes, and then provides the correct data. I believe this because the function is losing its original data source, and can't "re-connect".

As far as I can tell, there isn't a way for this to work natively on Google Sheets, so I'm wondering if there's a way to write a script to work around this issue.

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KqSGcIAn_X4v0YtGnGZVXaY4Je6B5SS5tz70Mw6U9uk/edit?usp=sharing

Screenshots = https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLx2b.jpg

Here's a script that works as intended, however, it only works when triggered from the Editor menu, I would like it to update automatically:

```
function updateDataTab() {
  
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  let range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 60, 77);
  let formulas = range.getFormulas();
  range.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.setFormulas(formulas);

}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated as I'm quite new to coding.

Edit: added code
Edit 2: Added clarification

Comment: How are you re-creating the Week1? I have tried to duplicate it and to copy the entire sheet into a new one and both worked out okay without any ref.

Comment: So for each new client, I create a copy of the whole file, within that file, I duplicate 'Week Template' and rename it 'Week [#]'. Now it's at this point that I'm getting the error. If you look at 'Data!A3', it currently shows said error, but if I double click and hit enter, the error goes away.

Comment: I suppose another way around this is to write a script that takes the product of columns E, K, & L, for each given circumstance (when column A says either "SQ", "BP", or "DL" that I tried to do with IF statements.

Comment: While a link to a external resource might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained, so, please edit the question to add the clarifications done in your comments and but also describe how and when the formulas are added to the relevant sheets.

Comment: My apologies @Rubén, still new around here. I have added the clarification and functions used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your spreadsheet you have set the formulas for several weeks in advance, in other words, the formulas include invalid references.

IMHO instead of refreshing the spreadsheet to make these formulas work, you should add the formulas after the new sheet is added. There are several ways to do this, i.e. you could use a custom menu to create the copy of the week template, renamed it add the formulas having references to this new sheet, or you could use an change installable trigger to add the formulas when a new sheet is inserted that meet certain criteria.

Comment: Ah okay. So I could write a script that inserts my above function every time a create a sheet containing the word "Week" or something along those lines?